# Does the Android debugger truncate debug messages?

Tags: android, sqlite, debugging, adb, truncation

Im asking because Im trying to debug a SQL query problem and adb only seems to show part of the SQL string and chops off the end.

Im getting an "unrecognized token" error when running a query:

```
W/System.err(18917): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "931C6752DF97CFDACD130A06CAE0E7DA6320DE2945FFFA0A65629BC687256DE3": , while compiling: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE (id IN (9781101134801,9781429535823,9780806532318,9781440609404,9781440644474,9781101184554,2940000052358,9780071633574,9781429516105,9781411433250,9781586488581,9780786537624,9781101188705,9781440697661,9780199717569,9781429580397,9781429979436,9781101187739,9781429959810,9781420119053,9781429954419,9781101218457,9781569757468,9780802196262,9781101213339,9781411428942,9781411428232,2940011807343,9780307272119,2940000248775,2940000273708,2940000278932,2940000274514,2940000400104,2940000336878,2940000281062,2940000400081,2940000281017,9780316005050,2940000336113,2940000367278,9781426847585,2940000244647,9780137058549,2940000248768,9780077422318,9781426833533,2940000244609,2940000274552,2940000244692,2940000336908,2940000400142,2940000277621,2940000400111,2940000392300,2940000228241,9780345464927,2940000336144,2940000807224,2940000277249,9780345515667,2940000336076,2940000336137,9780316086134,2940000273463,9780061429347,2940000392355,9781416549833,9780061998065,9780321700704,2940000400159,9781426806421,9781426840562,2940000273470,9781416587187,9781428507326,2940000313640,2940000277669,2940000336915,2940000338131,2940000244654,9780791487655,2940000277676,2940000392331,2940000273449,2940000313633,9781411431645,9780316040341,2940000248782,9780077395469,2940000248850,2940000336083,2940000367261,2940000273494,2940000228623,2940000228302,9780061959936,2940000367247,2940000244623,2940000274538,2940000280942,2940000336861,2940000367216,2940000277645,2940000228388,2940000338124,9780321703477,2940000248812,9780061962066,2940000338100,2940000277225,2940000392324,2940000278925,2940000248348,2940000277713,2940000273487,2940000336120,2940000367223,9780877797753,2940000274569,2940000336922,2940000336106,2940000313671,9780307264725,9780385533133,2940000248393,2940003039615,2940000336090,9780061916458,2940000338087,2940000244678,2940000277638,2940000281079,2940000400128,2940000338049,2940000367186,2940000313695,9780321702067,2940000248867,2940000277652,2940000400135,2940000338094,2940000248805,2940000277201,2940000248836,2940000982556,2940000228340,2940000367209,9780307593672,2940000336052,2940000278918,2940000277706,2940000336069,2940000248355,2940000277232,2940000280966,2940000338117,2940000248379,2940000277218,2940000313657,2940000341599,2940000248829,9780062002945,2940000313664,2940000274521,2940000367230,9780786955916,2940000277690,2940000248362,2940000362396,2940000244685,9780307272300,2940000273500,2940000313688,2940000281147,9781101443552,2940000248843,2940000273456,2940000228043,2940000274545,2940000392317,9780743258241,2940000982303,9781439168035,9780132103206,9781596916715,2940000313718,2940000392348,2940000244661,2940000400098,2940000400166,9780307271341,2940000313701,2940000367193,2940000277683,9781605043739,9780440334408,2940000338070,2940000244630,2940000338063,9780307719607,2940000336939,9780345464453,2940000336885,2940000367254,2940000336892,2940000338056,2940000244616,2940000392294,2940000313626,2940000093559,931C6752DF97CFDACD130A06CAE0E7DA6320DE2945FFFA0A65629BC687256DE3,88F21F69943935F0C31A803A6C3A639F242CDF18DC0570113888FE00569BAE45,9781411433786)) AND (id IN (2940000697375,9781423140344,9781101134801,9781433671074,9781101152140,9781429535823,9780806532318,9781429516174,9781440609404,9781440644474,9781101184554,2940000052358,9780071633574,9780761148340,9781429516105,2940000147467,9781411428485,9781411433250,9781586488581,9781414346304,9781101136775,9780786537624,9781101188705,9781440697661,9781429543637,9781414346311,9781101190111,9781565125858,9780199717569,9781596917248,9781429580397,9780786025145,9780786564743,9781429979436,9781101187739,2940000754603,9781420119053,9781429954419,9781101213339,9781440668890,9780307272119,2940000248775,2940000273708,2940000278932,2940000274514,2940000400104,2940000336878,2940000281062,2940000244562,2940000400081,2940000281017,9780316005050,2940000336113,29400
W/System.err(18917):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.native_compile(Native Method)
W/System.err(18917):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compile(SQLiteProgram.java:117)
W/System.err(18917):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:66)
W/System.err(18917):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
W/System.err(18917):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:59)
W/System.err(18917):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1286)
W/System.err(18917):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1259)
```

As you can see the query above appears truncated.

Comment: Did you get this via logcat in eclipse? You might want to try it from adb logcat on command line and see if you get the same result.
Given that the log in Android is a ring buffer of log entries, there probably is an internal limit to length.

Comment: I'd write long stuff like that to a file. Looks like it truncates around the 4K mark.

Comment: @cistearns: Yes, that output was from adb logcat on the command-line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dug into the Android open source code and confirmed that it does have a max message size just under 4k.

So it does look like that log entry is getting cut off.

From the current native C++ source (platform/system/core/include/cutils/logger.h)  :

```
struct logger_entry {
    uint16_t    len;    /* length of the payload */
    uint16_t    __pad;  /* no matter what, we get 2 bytes of padding */
    int32_t     pid;    /* generating process's pid */
    int32_t     tid;    /* generating process's tid */
    int32_t     sec;    /* seconds since Epoch */
    int32_t     nsec;   /* nanoseconds */
    char        msg[0]; /* the entry's payload */
};
#define LOGGER_ENTRY_MAX_LEN        (4*1024)
#define LOGGER_ENTRY_MAX_PAYLOAD    \
    (LOGGER_ENTRY_MAX_LEN - sizeof(struct logger_entry))
```